# Image slider issue with Prestashop

Tags: themes, prestashop

I am new to Prestashop. I am using using Prestashop and have installed a theme which comes with a slider on the homepage.

The theme-slider disables the default Prestashop slider. The issue is, I would like to disable the theme-slider and put the default slider on the homepage.

I have disabled the theme-slider, but I am not able to put the default slider on the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to reset module called "Image slider for your homepage"

Hope this works for you ;)